# Unable to use XChat

Tags: proxy, irc, xchat

I have XChat installed, and when I start it, I get errors:

```
Looking up irc.mintirc.net
Looking up 172.16.1.10
Connecting to 172.16.1.10 (172.16.1.10) port 8080...
HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
Proxy traversal failed.
Stopped previous connection attempt (pid=20871)
```

I am behind a proxy server, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try editing the MintIRC network parameters and check "Bypass proxy server". Then close the window, and try to connect again.

If it doesn't work, uncheck "Bypass proxy server" and go to the general preferences of Xchat. There is a network section where you can specify any information needed by the proxy. Ask your IT team if you need any information.

Comment: Now I get following error

**Looking up irc.mintirc.net'**  
** Unknown host. Maybe you misspelled it?**  
**Cycling to next server in MintIRC...**  
** Disconnected ().**

Comment: try to connect to another irc server like ubuntu or freenode. let me know if there is an error in a new comment.

Comment: I tried many of them, and get the same error

Comment: in order to acces to the internet with Internet or Firefox, do you need a proxy or to configure something for the network ?

Comment: yes, using proxy everywhere.. getting same response in using xchat on windows too..

Comment: so you may have to ask your IT staff to unlock irc ports on the proxy/firewall, or to give you the necessary informations